# Socket.IO Node js socket.emit slow

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

My problem is that socket.emit is taking so much time to send the data to the server, i have tried anything but i got no results, this is the code:

**Client side**

```
$( "#mensaje" ).keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        $('.botonEnviarMensaje').click();
    }
  });

$('.botonEnviarMensaje').click(function(){
    var myInput = document.getElementById("mensaje");
    if(!isEmpty(myInput.value)){
        socket.emit('newMessage',dataPerson,myInput.value)
        console.log("envie un mensaje")
    }
    $('#mensaje').val('');
})
```

**Server side**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
const util = require('util')

app.use('/',express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public')));
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../../public/Login/index.html'))
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('newMessage',function(data,value){
        console.log("llego un mensaje")
        io.sockets.emit('messageAll',data,value);
    })


});
```

Comment: Before emitting the data on socket from client side ,please check the connected listener is on only emit data after the socket passed the connect state.So you will be able to check weather the time for emitting is more or the socket is taking time to connect.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: In a better way i suggest io.connection should emit like 'connected' kind of listener and same should be listened on client side socket.on('connected') and handle the emit of **newMessage** from the same and newMessage should be listened outside connection directly .By this you will exactly understand the client socket is successfully connected and then emit can proceed timestamp at this  time and the time when newMessage listened to it will tell you the emit is not slow.